# Eigenvector, solving Ax=b

Tags: linear-algebra

Hi I have another question where I don’t really know where to start....

Let A be a symmetric 3x3 matrix, with EV1 being (0,0,1) for $\lambda_1$=0 and EV2 b=(2,1,0) for $\lambda_2=1$. the third Eigenvalue be negativ.

With b from above give one solution for Ax=b

I honestly have no idea where to start, I can calculate the third eigenvector, and I know that the determinant of A is 0. I first thought of Cramer’s rule, but then I would have to divide by 0.

The only vague thing i could possibly think of is to go back to

$$Ax=\lambda x $$

So i know lambda and x that would give me

A * (2,1,0)^t=1 * (2,10)

And this could only be true if A = I

So the solution would be x1=1 x2=1 and x3 = 0,

But i guess this is just stupid

I honestly have no idea...

Many thanks

Comment: You know that $b$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $1$, correct? If so, then the equation $Ax=b$ has a solution in $x=b$.

Comment: May I ask why, I would love to understand....?

Comment: Your problem is you have 2 Eigen values and the corresponding eigenvectors and you need to find the 3rd?

Comment: No I have to solve for b, b being the second eigenvector

Comment: Well it follows from the definitions. We know that $b$ has eigenvalue $1$, so we have $Ab=1\cdot b=b$.

Comment: Yes that's definitely a way.

Comment: @Dave That is what i basically tried to reason in the last paragraph, so than A hast to be the Identity matrix, bc lambda =1 ...?

Comment: @Lily No, one eigenvalue of $A$ is $0$, so its determinant is also $0$

Comment: @ShubhamJohri  Oh , yes i actually concluded that above..... but how, without knowing a can i conclude that ax=b is b

Comment: What is $\vec b$? is it $(2,1,0)$ or $(0,0,1)$? Or do we have to find the solution for both of them?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri  its 2,1,0

Comment: @Lillys just because $Ab=b$ does not mean that $A=I$. If it were true for all vectors $b$ then we would have $A=I$, but we're only saying $Ab=b$ for the given vector $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the eigenvector $\vec b, A\vec b=\lambda\vec b\implies\vec b=A\cdot\frac{\vec b}\lambda\ (\lambda\ne0)$

So one solution for the system $A\vec x=\vec b$ for eigenvector $\vec b=[2,1,0]^T$ corresponding to the non-zero eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ is $\vec b/\lambda$. Additionally, since $\det A=0$, the system $A\vec x=\vec b$ can have either no or infinitely many solutions. Since one solution $\vec b/\lambda$ has been shown to exist, we know that infinitely many solutions exist.

Note that $\vec x=\frac{\vec b}\lambda+k\cdot[0,0,1]^T,k\in\Bbb R$, will always be a solution to the system as $A(\frac{\vec b}\lambda+k\cdot[0,0,1]^T)=\vec b+k\cdot A[0,0,1]^T=\vec b\ \because A[0,0,1]^T=0$